# preventing many IF statements in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C#. In my program, when I click a button, I enable a pair of   combo boxes on a panel and make the panel visible
 if  the previous combo boxes have values and the panel is visible.   I am doing this for a pair of 5 combo  boxes on 5   panels in order.
    Each level is made up of a pair of combo boxes which are enabled on a panel  and the panel made visible only when the previous panel is visible and combo boxes have values. The first level is always visible.
    Example:  I don't want to this.

```
private void btnAddLevel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboSort1.SelectedIndex > -1 && cboDir1.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            cboSort2.Enabled = true;
            cboDir2.Enabled = true;
            cboDir2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            pnlSort2.Visible = true;
        } 
        if (cboSort2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cboDir2.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            cboSort3.Enabled = true;
            cboDir3.Enabled = true;
            cboDir3.SelectedIndex = 0;
            pnlSort3.Visible = true;
        }
        if (cboSort3.SelectedIndex > -1 && cboDir3.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            cboSort4.Enabled = true;
            cboDir4.Enabled = true;
            cboDir4.SelectedIndex = 0;
            pnlSort4.Visible = true;
        }
        if (cboSort4.SelectedIndex > -1 && cboDir4.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            cboSort5.Enabled = true;
            cboDir5.Enabled = true;
            cboDir5.SelectedIndex = 0;
            pnlSort5.Visible = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: why not try like this (calculate Enabled/SelectIndex/Visible for each control): cboSort2.Enabled=pnlSort1.Visible == true && pnlSort3.Visible== false;cboSort2.SelectedIndex =pnlSort1.Visible == true && pnlSort3.Visible== false?-1:0;

Comment: This would probably be a good fit for a list a helper method and a foreach

Comment: Start with: don't write `if(condition == true)`.  Write `if (condition)`.  The first means "if it is true that condition is true", which is a strange way to say "if condition is true".  Similarly, don't say `if (condition == false)`.  Say `if (!condition)`.

Comment: Next: can you give an example of the mostly-duplicated code? By seeing what is the same and what is different we can advise you on how to make a helper method.

Comment: You could also have a look at the chain of responsibility pattern

Comment: I have edited my code in the question. It shows the whole code for adding a new combo box. Thanks @EricLippert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching the way how to remove conditions from the code, probably the best way of optimization will look like:

```
cboSort2.Enabled = !pnlSort1.Visible && pnlSort3.Visible;
cboDir2.Enabled = !pnlSort1.Visible && pnlSort3.Visible;
pnlSort2.Visible = !pnlSort1.Visible && pnlSort3.Visible;
cboSort3.Enabled = (cboSort2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cboDir2.SelectedIndex > -1);
cboDir3.Enabled = (cboSort2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cboDir2.SelectedIndex > -1);
pnlSort3.Visible = (cboSort2.SelectedIndex > -1 && cboDir2.SelectedIndex > -1);
```

It will allow you control each control Visibility, but in case of complex conditions can make your code not readable.
P.S. It is up to you. I see nothing bad in multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Although it still has multiple conditions but fewer lines than what I had earlier. I also do not see anything bad in multiple conditions but I'm just trying to  use the least number of lines as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was bored..

So you could do something like this. The advantage is that you can easily add more functionality (if and when you need)

**Class to hold controls and logic**

```
public class DisplayPanel
{
    public Panel Panel { get; set; }
    public ComboBox Sort { get; set; }
    public ComboBox Dir { get; set; }

    ...

    public DisplayPanel(Panel panel, ComboBox Sort, ComboBox Dir ...)
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool Validated()
    {
        // what ever your validate critria is here i.e
        // what makes this panel complete to show the next panel
    }

    public bool Activate()
    {
        ...
    }
    public bool Deactive()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Main form**

```
public class MainForm
{
    List<DisplayPanel> _panels;
    ...
```

**Initialize the list**

```
private void Setup()
{
    _panels = new List<DisplayPanel>
    {
        new DisplayPanel(...),
        new DisplayPanel(...),
        ...
    };
}
```

**A foreach to validate everythign**

```
public void OnDoSomething()
{
    // assuming you want the first panel always activated
    bool isNextValidated = true;

    // basically just check each panel to see if it needs to be displayed
    foreach (var displayPanel in _panels)
    {
        // if this panel is validated then activate it
        // check to see if the next panel needs activating
        if(isNextValidated)
        {
            displayPanel.Activate();
            isNextValidated = displayPanel.Validated();
        }
        else
        {
            displayPanel.Deactive();
        }                    
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll have to add pepper and salt to taste, but its neat and scalable and keeps everything [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

You only need to tweak the validation logic in one place, and you only need to set the activation and deactivation logic in one place